# if an app on google play reverse engineerd will the crashes occurs in it appear in the crashes of my app on google play console?

Tags: android, crash, reverse-engineering, google-play-console

I have upload an app on google play console . In the app there is an activity that is only visible for me as it controls some things in the app. I tried to open the app from different accounts to ensure that it's only visible for me. what happened with me is that when I opened google play console I found a crash from this activity on a device that I don't know ! This crash was a null pointer exception at line 83 . when I opened line 83 in my activity I found that it is an empty line !! Does this means that my app is currently reverse engineered ?

Answer (score 1):

It could mean that. People do it, especially if there are paid features they want to for free.

It could also be a crash report from an older version, where line 83 actually contained code. Even if the Activity isn't exported, a rooted device can launch it.

Comment: How can a rooted device see it ? I am making it visible only when the signed in user in the app is me how can rooted devices see that?

Comment: Just because you don't have a button to access the Activity from your app doesn't mean that Activity stops existing. Android has APIs to list all the components (Activities, Services, BroadcastReceivers, etc) that a specified app has registered in its Manifest. Root is needed to launch the ones that aren't exported, but anyone can list all the Activities in your app. There are apps on the Play Store for this.

Comment: Shortcut Master is one.